# Editing Excel Sheet with formulas using C++

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I have an excel sheet "Test.xlsx" in which some of the cell values has been referenced from another excel sheet using formula "='C:[Sample.xlsx]Sheet1'!B14". I did open Smaple.xlsx, change the value of the cell B14 in sheet 1, save it and close. But I did not see the values in the Test.xlsx update unless I double click on the cell where the formula has been referenced to. I have tried with "Excel Options-> Advanced ->General and un-checking Ask to update automatic link" Can someone help me with the issue?

Comment: do you have the same issue with formulas within the same excel workbook as well? (I'm wondering if you have manual calculations not automatic on: File > Options > Formulas > Workbook Calculation). Also how is this related to C++?